# How to create an UIScrollView that allows paging and zooming of UIImageViews?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, paging, zooming

I have tried to make a UIScrollView that allows a paging of various UIImageView and zoom every image. My first idea was to create a UIScrollView to paging and then create a UIScrollView for every UIImageView that allows me to zoom that image.

I know that there is a PhotoScroller Demo from Apple, but it is very complex, I really don't need the Tiles functionality.

Do you know any tutorial that talks about that?

Comment: have u got the solution? please provide some hint. i am facing same issue and yes apple document is very complex.

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good WWDC 2010 video, Designing Apps with Scroll Views, which accompanies the PhotoScroller code. The first half describes what you want, the second half is all about tiling. Watch the first half.

Open [Apple Developer Video Archive](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/) and then choose video 5, session 104, "Designing Apps with Scroll Views".

(developer login required)

Comment: any possibility of providing a link?

Comment: @RyanArtecona, see updated answer - requires developer membership to view

Comment: Thank you, I already read that tutorial but the tiling code it a bit difficult to me and is not what I am looking for.

Comment: You can ignore the tiling if u don't need it. I really do recommend the video, it builds up the code In small steps and is very clear.